# python generate period of a year in a list of dictionary

Tags: python

I am relatively new in python. I am trying generate a **period of a year in list of dictionary**; something like this,

```
[{'end_date': '2016-01-31', 'start_date': '2016-01-01'},
 {'end_date': '2016-01-31', 'start_date': '2016-01-01'},
 {'end_date': '2016-01-31', 'start_date': '2016-01-01'},
 {'end_date': '2016-01-31', 'start_date': '2016-01-01'},
 {'end_date': '2016-01-31', 'start_date': '2016-01-01'},
 {'end_date': '2016-01-31', 'start_date': '2016-01-01'},
 {'end_date': '2016-01-31', 'start_date': '2016-01-01'},
 {'end_date': '2016-01-31', 'start_date': '2016-01-01'},
 {'end_date': '2016-01-31', 'start_date': '2016-01-01'},
 {'end_date': '2016-01-31', 'start_date': '2016-01-01'},
 {'end_date': '2016-01-31', 'start_date': '2016-01-01'},
 {'end_date': '2016-01-31', 'start_date': '2016-01-01'}]
```

fot this output I have created the following function:

```
def get_periods():
    year = raw_input('Enter an year')
    list_of_periods = []
    for k in range(12):
        list_of_periods.append({'start_date': year + '-01-01','end_date': year + '-01-31'})
    return list_of_periods
```

Here I just want to pass the `year` and it should generate a period of a year, that is

```
[{'end_date': '2016-01-31', 'start_date': '2016-01-01'},
 {'end_date': '2016-02-29', 'start_date': '2016-02-01'},
 ....... and so on]
```

but I don't know how to iterate over `day` and `month` to create appropriate periods of a `year`. Also there are the issues of **leap year** and 
**month of 30** days or **month of 31** days.

Comment: As you say, there are several issues to resolve here, and it's not clear which one is the focus of this question. This makes this not an idea question for stackoverflow, which is why I'm downvoting it. (NOT because I want to discourage you!) I suggest you either repost here with a single clear question, or try a more interactive site like dreamincode.net or daniweb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`calendar.monthrange()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) to find the last day of any month:

```
import calendar

def get_periods():
    year = int(input('Enter a year: '))
    list_of_periods = []
    for month in range(1, 13):
        last_day = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
        list_of_periods.append({'start_date': '{0}-{1:02}-01'.format(year, month),
                                'end_date': '{0}-{1:02}-{2}'.format(year, month, last_day)})

    return list_of_periods

print(get_periods())
```

You will get a similar output to the following when you run this:

```
Enter a year: 2016
[{'start_date': '2016-01-01', 'end_date': '2016-01-31'}, 
 {'start_date': '2016-02-01', 'end_date': '2016-02-29'}, 
 {'start_date': '2016-03-01', 'end_date': '2016-03-31'}, 
 {'start_date': '2016-04-01', 'end_date': '2016-04-30'}, 
 ...]
```